# Hosting Python3 HTTPs server with unblocked terminal

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I am trying to publish a directory in Linux over HTTPs. I am using the below code.

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler,SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import ssl,os
web_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'as4-web')
cert_path=os.getcwd()
os.chdir(web_dir)

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('',8444)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket,
                                   server_side=True,
                                   certfile=os.path.join(cert_path,'cert.pem'),
                                   keyfile=os.path.join(cert_path,'key.pem'),
                                   ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
    print(f'Starting httpsd server on port 8444')
    httpd.serve_forever()

run()
```

After running the code, a prompt comes up to provide the PEM pass phrase like below.

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

After entering the passphrase, I want to run this program in background. Can someone please suggest how to achieve it? I looked for insights over internet but could not make it work unfortunately in my use case.